# How to deploy SDK Java with Eclipse?

Tags: java, excel, saml, okta

I want deploy **OKTA Java SDK** on Eclipse.

On the client side, we are using MS Excel **(VBA)**.
On the server side, we are serving the requests using pure Java Servlets.

Can anyone help me implement **OKTA Java SDK** ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Okta Java SDK? Can you explain your use case a bit more please?

Comment: actually in our excel project there is a login process we want to remove that login process and want to put okta login page in excel form browser for login page

Comment: If you put a web page in front of your excel spreadsheet, that might be possible, but I'm not sure you can invoke Okta login from inside Excel.

Comment: Hello @MattRaible i m trying to authenticate using okta through my java web application. There are many tutorials which show how to do that using spring. none of them have mentioned how to connect and authenticate to java using simple generic java.

Please let us know if it is possible to connect and authenticate using generic java at this point of time.

The following link on the official okta website says "We're hard at work on this Java Auth Code Example quickstart, please check back soon!".https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/okta-sign-in-page/java/generic

Waiting for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Okta SDK is for management tasks, we are looking into tie into our authentication API. For web apps, our first choice would be to use an OIDC (or OAuth 2) library.  There are a few OAuth libraries that have support for Servlets, I think [Apache Oltu](https://oltu.apache.org/) does.